# Start VeraCrypt "Portable" with relative path to a profilefolder?

Tags: portable, veracrypt

After extracting and executing the VeraCrypt binary from tmp, VeraCrypt creates a profile-folder containing the favourite Volumes and Configuration XMLs under `.VeraCrypt` in `~` as usual.

Is there any way to start the binary with a relative, custom set path to a profile-folder like I can do with a command-line/script for Thunderbird Portable or Firefox with e.g.

```
"$PWD/thunderbird/thunderbird" -no-remote -profile "$PWD/profilefolder"
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't find anything to that effect in the Linux documentation of VeraCrypt. Maybe a symbolic link from `~/.VeraCrypt` to a directory on the removable medium suits your needs and can serve as a work-around.

My other idea is to file an enhancement request with the VeraCrypt project to respect the [XDG Base Directory Specification](//specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) and store their configuration files in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/VeraCrypt` instead of the current location. Then you could set the `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` environment variable of the VeraCrypt application starter to point to a directory on the external storage medium. (Edit: [issue report by me](https://github.com/veracrypt/VeraCrypt/issues/53))